# Add quick view button on magento products

Tags: php, magento, button, reference

I am trying to add a quick view button on all magento products.  I am able to add the button next to the add to cart on product info page but not getting the reference for the product image.
This is my layout xml file.As the reference here is head it adds the button to the head of every page. I want it on every product image on that page.

```xml
<default>     
   <reference name="head">
       <block type="core/template" 
              name="mudit_swiftview_footer" 
              template="mudit_swiftview/swiftview.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 0):

check http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/em-quick-shop-quick-view-product.html.
they use JavaScript to insert the button on the fly. the example below will insert the quick view button on the top/left corner (in this case) on mouseover.

```
$(selectorObj.imgClass, this).bind('mouseover', function() {
                var o = $(this).offset();
                $('#em_quickshop_handler').attr('href',reloadurl).show()
                    .css({
                        'top':   o.top+(1.5 * $(this).height() - qsHandlerImg.height())/2+'px',
                        'left':  o.left+(1.5 * $(this).width() - qsHandlerImg.width())/2+'px',
                        'visibility': 'visible'
                    });
            });


_qsJnit({
        itemClass : '.products-grid li.item', //selector for each items in catalog product list,use to insert quickshop image
        aClass : 'a.product-image', //selector for each a tag in product items,give us href for one product
        imgClass: '.product-image img' //class for quickshop href
    });
```

check their JS code to learn more.
hope it helps.